# OUT of universe, why so few craft models in SW: The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In the original trilogy we get to see at least X-, Y-, A- and B- wing; and TIE -fighter, -advanced, -bomber and -interceptor. But in the new film all that is basically reduced to X-wing vs TIE fighter.

**I'm more interested in out-of-universe explanations, what creative process led them to reduce the variety of craft in the film** (in-universe is covered here: [Where were the capital ships and bombers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112113/where-were-the-capital-ships-and-bombers))

Is there any behind the scenes out there that addresses this particular point?

Comment: There are at least two variants each of TIE Fighters and X-Wings in *TFA*.

Comment: Indeed, where were the B-wings?  They make an appearance in ROTJ to replace Y-wings, but aren't present 30 years later?   Booo...

Comment: @Ross Someone pointed out on one of my questions that most of the ship battles in *TFA* happen in-atmosphere, and that the X-Wing has been redesigned to be able to do that. Perhaps the other ship models simply aren't good for in-atmo battle.

Comment: Excellent question! Disney being disney, this seems 100% counter-intuitive.

Comment: My personal guess (NOT backed up by any data) is that the marketing appeal of rare models only known to true fans is extremely low compared to a few models - compare that to centralization of lines of smartphones that's been officially going on for 2 last years)

Comment: Because the Force Awakens was a bad movie... They had bad acting, bad ships, and a bad plot the wasn't even a good remake of A New Hope.

Answer (score 6):

Just a guess, but I would say the word is **Branding**.

Imagine a SW films without light sabers, Millenium Falcon<sup>1</sup>, triangular Star Destroyers, X-Wing, TIEs. Sure, there were other things in the original films, but none of them (with maybe the exception of Implerial Shuttles and Fett's ship) were so easily recognizable.

Sure, there are lots of SW fans that watch the movies every few months and can say "Look, this is an A-Wing series X-900, you can tell by the exhaust design. And that hull number already appeared in ROTJ!", but the film has chosen to cater more to the big masses that have seen the film a few times and can only recognize the most iconic models.

<sup>1</sup>For the time of the last film it should be almost a century old. Show me any piece of equipment that is being regularly used a century after being fabricated (and that discounts that the MF has had some very hard beatings).

Comment: Kinda makes you wonder what percentage of the Falcon is still "original manufacturer equipment". (Probably not question worthy, because I doubt any source counts frame numbers or anything like that.)

Comment: in Return of the Jedi, a great many TIE fighters were the Interceptor variant, not the one from previous movies.

Comment: This answer rather responds to the question "Why does the new film show X-Wing and Tie Fighters?", rather than the question "Why does the film show nothing except X-Wing and Tie Fighters?".