# What is known of the status of the New Republic fleet at the end of The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

So after the capital of the New Republic was

> destroyed

What happened to the fleet?

This [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113526/what-is-the-status-of-the-new-republic-fleet-at-the-end-of-the-force-awakens?noredirect=1#comment273261_113526) simply mentions it was destroyed, but doesn't elaborate if its 100%, partial, or we just don't know. In the past things have been destroyed- namely the Jedi Order- but we know that wasn't exactly 100%.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your use of spoiler tags.

Comment: @PointlessSpike yeah I know. Should I just unspoiler it?

Comment: Feel free to revert my edit if you disagree, but I think the fate of the fleet isn't much of a spoiler- and it does say "At the end of The Force Awakens" in the title, so readers will know there are spoilers by reading that.

Answer (score 4):

1. According to WGA script, we can confirm that, as far as Resistance knows, it's 100% gone

   ```
   LEIA
   (eyes on datacard)
   The First Order: they're charging the weapon again, now.
   (then, heart sinking)
   Our system is the next target.
   C-3PO
   Oh my. Without the Republic fleet, we're doomed.
   ```
2. As to why the Republic fleet is gone, it was covered in detail in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112114/976), short version being that Foster Novelization details that 900 ships of Republic fleet were destroyed with Hosnian System.

   That answer also details that New Republic explicitly was very tree-hugging-peacenic, passed a Demilitarization act as soon as peace with Empire was signed; and clearly was not the type of entity that would have fleets of warships all over the place.
3. Even if some spotted rare ships out of Hosnian remained, they would have had NO command and control to order them to do anything (command and control is gone with Hosnian Prime), and their last orders were peaceful disposition.

Comment: in essence the resistance is almost as bad off as the rebellion before them in the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Only the Command Warships of the New Republic were destroyed. With enough sense we can tell that the rest of the defense fleet would join the Resistance to re-estabilish democratic rule over the galaxy.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer? Would you happen to be able to quote your source for that? I'd be interested in knowing how you arrived at this conclusion.

Comment: @Mithrandir I would assume that Jared means the more important and powerful warships of the fleet were stationed near the New Republic capital star system, and thus were destroyed alongside the star system.