# Why didn't the Resistance use Y wing bombers to assault SKB in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Why didn't the Resistance assaulting Starkiller Base use Y wing bombers?

It seems silly to me to conduct a bombing run or assault on a hard target without using craft designed specifically for bombing.

It is at least mentioned in passing that the Republic may be quietly funding them, so why did they not employ Y wings?

Comment: This is basically answered in the question http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112113/where-were-the-capital-ships-and-bombers - plus the [T 70 X-Wing](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/T-70_X-wing_fighter) ALSO replaced the Y-Wings as bomber.

Comment: Fair enough! I wasn't aware that the T70 was a fighter-bomber rather than just a space fighter, as with the T65, thanks

Comment: It's kinda sad that, even though JJ removed all the trade shenanigans from the movie... the reason we don't see more iconic crafts is because of budget. (The budget for the Republic, not the movie)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, the T-70 XWING varient replaced the T-65 XWING.

The T-65 was a space escort/fighter while the T-70 filled more of a fighter/bomber role and as such made it a suitable craft for the resistance to use in assaulting SKB.

Also, they had no Y Wings as they were very low on resources and even their T-70 XWING craft were given to them or loaned from senators/politicians or security groups etc.